# Use array, delete values, then restore array

Tags: arrays, autoit

My code loops; on each cycle I need to use an array, delete some or all values, then reset the array to its original state, then continue to the next cycle. Example:

```
$myArray[5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

_ArrayDelete($myArray, $i) ; Delete at the specified index
```

After this cycle runs, I need to set  `$myArray[5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` again. Is there another way of doing this (without using `_ArrayAdd()`)?

Comment: @LP.Gonçalves That's [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) (question about an attempted solution rather than the actual problem); describe what you are trying to achieve instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the arrayDelete function return an altered copy of the array, instead of modifying the original array itself.
Once you do that, you can use  something like this:

```
$tempArray = arrayDelete($myArray, $i);
// do stuff with $tempArray
// $myArray is not changed
```

Whether that is possible in your case, or how to implement this in arrayDelete, is impossible to say without more information form your end.

Answer (score 1):

Use local scope of variables in a function:

```
#include <array.au3>

Global $myArray[5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

For $i = 1 To 1000
    cycle($myArray)
Next

Func cycle($myArray) ; $myArray is a local copy inside the function
    _ArrayDisplay($myArray) ; to prove, it's the original
    _ArrayDelete($myArray,2) ; delete something
    _ArrayDisplay($myArray) ; to prove, it's altered
EndFunc   ;==>cycle
```

It's what I suggested: work with a (local) copy.

Answer (score 1):

avoid the redim penalty and just extract what you need

```
#include<array.au3>

local $myArray[5] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

   for $i = 0 to 4

    _ArrayDisplay(_ArrayExtract($myArray , $i))
    If $i = 4 Then $i = -1

  next
```